# Cordova navigation.notification.alert not working...[IOS]

Tags: cordova, phonegap-plugins, phonegap-build, cordova-3

I'm building my first phonegap/cordova project, and i'm testing this but it's not working, so this is my html:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
    <meta http-equiv="Content-type" content="text/html; charset=utf-8">
    <meta name="viewport" id="viewport" content="width=device-width, height=device-height, initial-scale=1.0, maximum-scale=1.0, user-scalable=no;" />
    <script type="text/javascript" charset="utf-8" src="cordova.js"></script>
    <script type="text/javascript" charset="utf-8">
        function onDeviceReady() {
            window.alert('Connected!');
            navigator.notification.alert("Cordova is ready!");
        }

        function onBodyLoad() {
            document.addEventListener("deviceready", onDeviceReady, false);
        }
    </script>
</head>
<body onload="onBodyLoad()">
<h1>HelloWorld</h1>
<p>This is a sample Cordova application.</p>
</body>
</html>
```

my plugin:

> org.apache.cordova.dialogs 0.2.9 "Notification"

The "window.alert" works, but the "navigator.notification.alert" never works...

i'm using this command to emulate:

```
cordova emulate iOS
```

My cordova version is:
3.5

Any idea about what could be wrong in my code?

Comment: Did you verify the plugin's installation with `cordova plugins list`? Do you see any error messages? You can use Safari's Javascript console to debug apps running in the iOS Simulator: http://phonegap-tips.com/articles/debugging-ios-phonegap-apps-with-safaris-web-inspector.html

Answer (score 0):

It's working now, i just have to build my application, i think that only use "cordova emulate iOS" doesn´t work, i´ve to "cordova build ios" before emulate.

Comment: If you use `cordova run ios`that will both build and run/emulate